# PHP generate random number without start with 0 or 00

Tags: php, function, random

i've create a function to generate a `random number` but i want to remove **`0`** from this number and i want to **start** this number with **any** number **different** to **`0`**.

**My Code:**

```
function createRandomNumber() {
    $chars = "07659242202345640248765924276987346549823433445754767659242599";
    srand ( ( double ) microtime () * 1000000 );
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '';
    while ( $i <= 7 ) {
          $num = rand () % 33;      
          $tmp = substr ( $chars, $num, 1 );
          $pass = $pass . $tmp;
          $i ++;
    }
    return $pass;
}
```

Comment: Ehm, can you provide your expected output? You want 0 (it is in $chars) and you don't want 0?

Comment: Why not simply create your random number using [mt_rand()](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) with numeric arguments for min and mx value?

Comment: @bub i don't want 0

Comment: So why don't you delte the 0 in $chars?

Comment: @MarkBaker how can i do ?

Comment: @mahmoudismail - you can start by reading the documentation that I linked, especially the bit about __parameters__

Comment: ok thank you all , it's solved.

Comment: `srand ( ( double ) microtime () * 1000000 );` Bad first step, as `srand()` takes an integer argument, not a float

Comment: If you want to skip the '0' characters then I suggest you change your while condition to `while (strlen($pass) < 8)`. In the loop add a check like this `if ($tmp === '0') continue;` to avoid appending '0' to `$pass`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the default random number function, i.e.

```
<?php
mt_rand(1,7000);
?>
```

[PHP Manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).

> **NOTE:** The below is not secure and while producing the desired output, this is not in any way a *Cryptographically Secure* number generator such as [`random_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php).

If you looking for something secure from a security through obscurity point of view, then developing your own function is an option. You could keep your function as is and just do a string replace if the first char is "0".

```
function createRandomNumber() {
    $chars = "07659242202345640248765924276987346549823433445754767659242599";
    srand ( ( double ) microtime () * 1000000 );
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '';
    while ( $i <= 7 ) {
          $num = rand () % 33;      
          $tmp = substr ( $chars, $num, 1 );
          $pass = $pass . $tmp;
          $i ++;
    }
    if($pass[0] == "0" ) {$pass = substr( $pass, 1);}
        return $pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this weird homebrew really "more secure"?

Comment: In the php manual for mt_rand it stats: "Caution
This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead."

Comment: @mrheroux, but you _aren't_ using any of those functions. Believe me, what you have isn't (even remotely) cryptographically secure, either. I'd be willing to be it's _considerably less secure_ than the `mt_rand()` solution. Instead of writing your own complex function, please just use one of the functions listed in the manual.

Comment: I didn't write it, @mahmoudismail did. I just gave him an option of using his solution and provided the correct way to do it. Since we are unaware if he created this nonsense for a reason, such as security through obscurity.

Comment: @mrheroux, it's fine to work with the OP's code, but please don't suggest it's in any way "more secure". That does a disservice to the OP and the community.

Comment: Understandable. STO is not worth further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I've made 2 changes on your code (the commented lines).

```
function createRandomNumber() {
    $chars = "07659242202345640248765924276987346549823433445754767659242599";
    srand ( ( double ) microtime () * 1000000 );
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '';
    // Loop until $pass has 8-characters
    while ( strlen($pass) < 8 ) {
          $num = rand () % 33;      
          $tmp = substr ( $chars, $num, 1 );
          // avoid leading '0'
          if (strlen($pass) === 0 && $tmp === '0') continue;
          $pass = $pass . $tmp;
          $i ++;
    }
    return $pass;
}
```

Hope this helps.